# Jenkins email-ext plugin encoding seting for emailable-report.html

Tags: email, jenkins

I am using email-ext plugin in my job to send the generated TestNG report via email. I have some Japanese characters in the generated emailable-report.html.
My email-ext plugin config looks like this:
[image]

But when received the email, all the Japanese characters in the emailable-report.html report doesn't show as expected.Instead, they show like this:
[image]

I searched google but don't find anywhere I can set the encoding. Does anybody know what the problem is?

**BTW: In Manage Jenkins-->Configure System-->E-mail Notification--Charset, I've already set the value to 'utf-8'.**

Comment: I looked at the source code of the email i'm getting and i see this `<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8">`, so i know it is coming across as UTF-8.  Did you confirm your client email app has the proper language pack, or ability to display japanese characters?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to `JAVA_OPTS`.